# Is there a way to put strings in the `string.insert("", "")` function?

Tags: c++

So here's the line of my code to which I'm referring:

```
x.insert("a", "hello");
```

I'm trying to insert the string "hello" after each "a" in a string. Is it possible to do this with the `insert` function?

Comment: First argument to [**string::insert**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/) is a `position`, not another string.

Comment: but my position is where the letter 'a' is in a string. Is there a way to set "a" to a variable of some sort to make it read as a position?

Comment: Use [**string::find**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) first to find the offset.

Comment: Okay got it, now how do I put that back in the string::insert function?

Comment: what kind of format is x? only has 'a' or any format?

Comment: @user1950701 Read the doc. `string& insert ( size_t position_to_insert_at, const string& original_string );`

Comment: Okay thanks for that, here's my whole code btw, it wouldn't let me insert it al as "code"  #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int a = 1;
string e="e";
string i="i";
string o="o";
string u="u";
string y="y";
int main(void) //tells a pirate story
{

string x;
cin>>x;
x.find("a");
x.insert(1, "app");
cout<<x<<endl;
cin.get();
return 0;
}

Comment: @user1950701 Edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: @user1950701, It told you where `"a"` was in the string (or if it was even in there) and you ignored it and passed in a random position instead.

Comment: Okay so I did this int y = x.find("a");
x.insert(wow, "app"); and now it inserts "app" only at one point in the string instead of all of them, for example the string "aaa" would turn into "aleaaa" instead of "aleaaleaalea" i know it's a bit confusing.. but how do I get it to insert the string every time "a" is found?

Comment: @user1950701, `find()` takes a position to start looking. Keep starting after the last point until it isn't found.

Answer (score 2):

> is it not possible to do this with the insert function?

That's right, you can't do this with a single call to `insert()` since `std::string` does not have an `insert()` function with these semantics.

Answer (score 2):

Following [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170263/is-there-a-way-to-put-strings-in-the-string-insert-function#comment19634577_14170357), here is how you can do this in a (non-infinite) loop:

```
void insert_after_each(std::string& s, const std::string& target, const std::string& to_insert)
{
    for (std::string::size_type i = s.find(target);
        i != std::string::npos;
        i = s.find(target, i + target.size() + to_insert.size()))
    {
        s.insert(i + target.size(), to_insert);
    }
}
```

This inserts the text after (what I call) the `target` string and skips past the target text ("a") and the inserted text ("hello") in each iteration.

### Sample usage:

```
std::string s = "A cat sat on a mat";
insert_after_each(s, "a", "hello");
assert(s == "A cahellot sahellot on ahello mahellot");
```

Comment: thanks, but what do I replace insert_at_each with and "target" with?

Comment: Actually nvm on that part, thank you very much it works almost flawless now! :) but when i have spaces between two words it only reads it as one word

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "almost flawless", it inserts "hello" after each "a" in a string. It knows nothing of "words" but that is because we're merely dealing with `string`s here. It sounds like you have another requirement here. Perhaps `insert_at_each(s, " a ", "hello ");` will do what you want, but it's difficult to tell.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is find the position of `a` by using [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) then call [std::string::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) to insert string to the right position. For example:

C++11

```
 auto pos = x.find("a"); 
 x.insert(pos, "app");
```

C++03:

```
  std::string b(x);
  int n = 0;
  for(std::string::iterator iter = x.begin(); iter!=x.end(); ++iter)
  {
    if ((*iter) == 'a')
    {
      int pos = rep.size()* n + distance(x.begin(), iter);
      cout << distance(x.begin(), iter) << " " << rep.size() << endl;
      b.insert(pos,"app");
      n++;
    }    
  }
```

Now string `b` is what you are after.

Comment: I'm getting the error "ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'pos' with no type"

Comment: @user1950701: Replace `auto` with `std::string::size_type`

Comment: @billz Thanks that seemed to work :) except I'm still having the issue of it only replacing the first "a" in the string, and ignoring the others. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1950701 you need to loop through string

Comment: ah..sorry I must sound like a total noob but how exactly would I do that?

Comment: @user1950701: Simply keep assigning `pos = x.find("a");` in a `for`- or a `while`-loop and repeat the call to `x.insert(pos, "app");` until no such substring is found (this case is covered in the linked documentation).

Comment: `while ((position = x.find("a")) != std::string::npos)` is a good start.

Comment: Careful though, if the string you are inserting has an `a` in it, it will be a neverending loop. It would be best to store the result in a separate string or something along those lines.

Comment: Okay I'll change it to "opp" then, so in my while loop should I have: while ((position = x.find("a")) != std::string::npos){x.find("a")} ?

Comment: sorry to keep bothering oyu guys, but I did the while loop above and now its just a never ending loop. anyway to fix this?

Comment: I'd like to take dreamlax's idea, operate on a second string instead. see my updated answer.

Comment: i dont think it's working, when i tpye in "aaa" the result is "aaappppppaaa"

Comment: I find it hard to believe that these two examples are equivalent to each other.